# How to stop scrolling in subview in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have two `viewControllers` added into the `scrollView` such that in second viewController I have a `subView` where images are scrolled. I want to stop scrolling the `viewController` when I'm scrolling the images in `subView`.

Comment: Could you just provide an image, of what you have? It would help.

Comment: i got the answer [scrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];  thank u.Can u please say how to increase the scroll speed

Answer (score 1):

You implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and in this function:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     if(scrollView == imagesScrollView){
           mainScrollView.scrollEnables = NO;
        }
}
```

and after dragging enable it again:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
   {
        mainScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
  }
```